# Overlapping lines in ```align*``` and ```equation``` environment

Tags: align

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[centerlast]{caption2}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\def\toright#1{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\title{\vspace{-4cm}\textbf{Mathematical Modelling}}
\author{Manjoy Das}
\affil{\textbf{Mail me -}\;XXXX}
\affil{\textbf{Hello me -}\;XXXXXX}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\begin{document}
We know that
\begin{align}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \sum_{n=0}^N P_n(t)&=1\nonumber\\
    \Longrightarrow  P_0(t)+\sum_{n=1}^N P_n(t)&=1\nonumber\\
    \Longrightarrow  P_0(t)=1-\sum_{n=1}^N P_n(t)&=
    1-\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}
\end{align}
Thus from $(4)$ and $(5)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    P_n(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}, & 1\le n\le N, t\ge 0\\
        1-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}, & n=0, t\ge 0
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation*}
Thus the number of departures in time $t$ follows the Poisson distribution.
\end{document}
```

Why are these lines overlapping?

[image: without \]

To remove these overlapping, I needed to put `\\` after `\end{align}` and `\end{equation*}`.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[centerlast]{caption2}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\def\toright#1{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\title{\vspace{-4cm}\textbf{Mathematical Modelling}}
\author{Manjoy Das}
\affil{\textbf{Mail me -}\;XXXX}
\affil{\textbf{Hello me -}\;XXXXXX}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\begin{document}
We know that
\begin{align}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \sum_{n=0}^N P_n(t)&=1\nonumber\\
    \Longrightarrow  P_0(t)+\sum_{n=1}^N P_n(t)&=1\nonumber\\
    \Longrightarrow  P_0(t)=1-\sum_{n=1}^N P_n(t)&=
    1-\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}
\end{align}\\
Thus from $(4)$ and $(5)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    P_n(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}, & 1\le n\le N, t\ge 0\\
        1-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}, & n=0, t\ge 0
    \end{cases}\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{equation*}\\
Thus the number of departures in time $t$ follows the Poisson distribution.
Thus the number of departures in time $t$ follows the Poisson distribution.
\end{document}
```

[image: with \]

Comment: you have  a  spurious `\\ ` making a blank last row. but  for the second `align*` why `align*` as you only have one row and no alignment specified?

Comment: you get no overlapping from your full example after removing the `\\ ` [texlive 2022 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M2SH.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in the edit section, I mentioned that this edit had been made to clarify thing that was happening if I added ```\\``` and if I didn't. The first image was obtained after adding ```\\``` while the 2nd one obtained after removing ```\\```.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the image is a part of a long theory in which I used (1) to (4) numbered equations where these things were not happening. But from this segment, I am facing such troubles. Even after this segment, if I don't use ```\\``` in the last line of every ```align*``` or ```equation``` environment, lines are getting overlapped.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle with the preambles mentioned in my question, just try the following coding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have shown my entire work and posted it newly. Hope this time the error can be found.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle equation number is not my problem. My problem is that extra numbering that is occurring just after the number ```(5)```. How can I show my previous numbered equation that was at least 7 pages behind. Between ```(4)``` and ```(5)```, there are several equations

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if you get equation number ```(1)``` instead of ```(5)```, that's ok... But you should not get ```(2)``` right after ```(1)``` what I'm getting.

Comment: Again, I tried the code you posted and see no overlap after removing the trailing ``\\``

Comment: @egreg there must be something suspicious then. Thanks for your try

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't even know where the problem lies. Otherwise I would have posted that part. I understand your point. May be it's in the packages or somewhere other. I'm combining three different .tex files and may be that's why the problem is invisible to me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have changed the image with slight modification in the coding. Kindly check it

Comment: Why do you keep doing the same thing? You have completely reposted the example but again posted code of a document with no problem and an image of a completely different document which has problem over-printing but no indication of the code.  Post the image _of the result of the code you post_, not the image of a different document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Each time I posted the same code for which I'm getting the overlapping lines. That's why this time I did not post just the image of the pdf, but also posted the screenshot of my editor (on the left hand side). You can see the coding (on the left of the image) and the result that is generated after compiling (on the right side of the image). Why do I post different coding and resulted document? This image was taken from my TexStudio editor

Comment: No!! You have never posted an image generated by the code you posted. Your screenshot shows line 3300, your posted code has that text on line 53, so all we know is that something in the 2250 lines you have not shown is causing  a problem. Why can you not simply do as you are asking others to do, copy the code you posted here to a new document check it shows the problem and post code and result here. Posting images of a document we do not have is not useful @ManjoyDas

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is no overlapping when I copy and paste the posted code in a new document. But that is something more embarrassing. How can I find the reason why this is happening in this document only?

Comment: have you really never in all this time tested the code you posted until  now??? That is why we asked over and over again that you show the output of the code you posted, You need to fix your example so it shows the problem, otherwise no one can help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have been checking this over and over again in this same document. But I should have checked this on a different document. So is there no cure in this circumstances?

Comment: @ManjoyDas of course there is a cure. If you post an example someone will help, if you do not show any example of your problem we can not help

Answer (score 2):

If you do `texdoc amsmath` (maybe via the [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net) site), you can see on page 4

[image]

Well, a trailing `\\` does no harm in `aligned`, `gathered` or `alignedat`, but it's best to stick to the above recommendation anyway.

The paragraph above speaks about extra vertical space and doesn't mention that a number is generated in the numbered versions `align`, `gather` and `alignat`; indeed, the extra vertical space is because an empty equation is typeset.

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

We know that
\begin{align}
    \sum_{n=0}^N P_n(t)&=1\nonumber\\
    \Longrightarrow  P_0(t)+\sum_{n=1}^N P_n(t)&=1\nonumber\\
    \Longrightarrow  P_0(t)=1-\sum_{n=1}^N P_n(t)&=
      1-\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}
\end{align}
Thus from $(4)$ and $(5)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    P_n(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}, & 1\le n\le N, t\ge 0\\[2ex]
        1-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac{(\mu t)^{N-n} e^{-\mu t}}{(N-n)!}, & n=0, t\ge 0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I changed `align*` into `equation*`, because it's a single equation and added some vertical space between the two cases.

[image]

Also you shouldn't use `$(4)$` and similar, but rather `\eqref` with suitable labels for the equation you want to refer to.

Comment: Doing this, ```(1)``` numbered line and the next line is overlapping. And this is happening throughout the document

Comment: @ManjoyDas No. I copied your preamble and tried, there is no overlap.

Comment: Then why is this happening to me? I added screenshot

Comment: @ManjoyDas Your example code produces an equation numbered (1), so you have something else.

Comment: I would like to mention that I had to add ```\\``` after ```\end{align}``` to avoid overlapping in my entire document. That's why I added my complete packages that I had used to write this document.